# jquery smooth site navigation between divs

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to smoothly navigate between divs using jquery. I have a php website with 4 navigation divs. So when I click "staff" on the page I navigate to that div. How would I do this using jquery ?

This is how I´m using this:

```
<div id="top_links">
<p class="top_link"><a href="#Stofan">The Firm</a></p>
</div>
```

i´m trying to make it look like this website: http://themetrust.com/demos/solo/#services

I´m new to jquery. I cant see how I should do this so any suggestion would be a HUGE help.. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the `scrollTop` property with jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {

    //stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
    event.preventDefault();

    //get the href for this link and the offset from the top of the page for the target of that href
    var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
        oset  = $(href).offset().top;

    //animate the scroll to the selected element
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop : oset
    }, 1000, function () {

        //after the animation is complete, update the hash in the address bar so that the state is saved (if the user refreshed the page they can be brought back to this place, but that takes a bit more code)
        location.hash = href;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpegt/1/

This requires that your links are targeting elements on the page using the syntax: `#element-id`.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same in this case as `.bind()`.

**UPDATE**

One cool thing that you can do with this is add a custom easing method. If you use the jQuery Easing Plugin ( http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ ) then you can choose from lots of types of easing. I like easeInOutExpo for animating page scrolling.

Comment: Jasper: I cant get this to work using this code. How would I use this on this code: ?

    <div id="juris_links">
   
    <p class="top_link"><a href="#Stofan">The Firm</a></p>
    <p class="top_link"><a href="#Starfssvið">Areas of Expertise</a></p>
    <p class="staffid"><a href="#Staff">Staff</a></p>
    <p class="top_link"><a href="#Innheimtuþjónusta">Collection Service</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrollTo plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

The example page is using [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're using these libraries:

- [jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)
- [easySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)
- [visualNav](https://github.com/Mottie/visualNav)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use jQuery's `animate()` function to adjust the `window.scrollTop` property to align with the appropriate div.